# WPF DataGrid: ColumnHeaderStyle ContentTemplate is not shown in full height until after resizing

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, resize, toolkit

This might be a bug in the WPF Toolkit `DataGrid`.

In my Windows.Resources I define the following `ColumnHeaderStyle`:

```
<Style x:Name="ColumnStyle" x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="my:DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Because my columns are generated dynamically, I am defining the columns in code:

```
private void CreateColumn(Output output, int index)
{
    Binding textBinding = new Binding(string.Format("Relationships[{0}].Formula", index));
    DataGridTextColumn tc = new DataGridTextColumn();
    tc.Binding = textBinding;
    dg.Columns.Add(tc);
    tc.Header = output;
}
```

where `Output` is a simple class with `Name` and `Data` (string) properties.

What I observe is that **only the Name property** (first `TextBlock` control in the `ContentTemplate`'s `StackPanel`) **is shown**. When I drag one of these column headers, I see the entire header (including the Data `TextBlock`). Only **after manually resizing one of the columns are the column headers rendered correctly**. Is there a way to get the column headers to show up correctly in code?

**Update:** as requested, here is the rest of my code for the repro.

```
public class Input
{
    public Input() 
    {
        Relationships = new ObservableCollection<Relationship>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}

public class Output
{
    public Output() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Relationship
{
    public Relationship() { }

    public string Formula { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="GridTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RowHeaderIsMouseOverBrush" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RowBackgroundSelectedBrush" Color="Yellow" />
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2VisibilityConverter" />

        <Style x:Key="RowHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNS"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Name="ColumnStyle" x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="my:DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!-- from http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=9193 -->
        <Style x:Name="RowHeaderStyle" x:Key="RowHeaderStyle" TargetType="my:DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type my:DataGridRowHeader}}}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="5">|</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content.Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type my:DataGridRowHeader}}}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Formula, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CellEditTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Formula, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <my:DataGrid Name="dg" 
                     ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"
                     RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource RowHeaderStyle}"
                     HeadersVisibility="All" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And finally the code-behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Inputs = new List<Input>();
        Outputs = new List<Output>();

        Input i1 = new Input() { Name = "I 1", Data = "data 1" };
        Input i2 = new Input() { Name = "I 2", Data = "data 2" };


        Inputs.Add(i1); Inputs.Add(i2);

        Output o1 = new Output() { Name = "O 1", Data = "data 1" };
        Output o2 = new Output() { Name = "O 2", Data = "data 2" };
        Output o3 = new Output() { Name = "O 3", Data = "data 3" };

        Outputs.Add(o1); Outputs.Add(o2); Outputs.Add(o3);

        Relationship r1 = new Relationship() { Formula = "F1" };
        Relationship r2 = new Relationship() { Formula = "F2" };
        Relationship r3 = new Relationship() { Formula = "F3" };
        Relationship r4 = new Relationship() { Formula = "F4" };

        i1.Relationships.Add(r1);
        i1.Relationships.Add(r2);
        i2.Relationships.Add(r3);
        i2.Relationships.Add(r4);


        CreateColumn(o1, 0);
        CreateColumn(o2, 1);
        CreateColumn(o3, 2);

        dg.Items.Add(i1);
        dg.Items.Add(i2);
        dg.ColumnWidth = DataGridLength.SizeToHeader;
    }

    private void CreateColumn(Output output, int index)
    {
        Binding textBinding = new Binding(string.Format("Relationships[{0}].Formula", index));
        DataGridTextColumn tc = new DataGridTextColumn();
        tc.Binding = textBinding;
        dg.Columns.Add(tc);
        tc.Header = output;
    }

    private List<Output> Outputs { get; set; }
    private List<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed if the columns are created in the Loaded event handler, rather than in the constructor of the window.

Answer (score 0):

When using a simple DataGrid with ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}", and adding columns using your CreateColumn method, I'm not able to replicate this: both TextBlocks show up fine (on two separate lines) right away.

Could you paste your full DataGrid declaration, and any other styles you have that it might be using?

Also, what version of wpftoolkit are you using? I tested both with the June release and with the DataGrid included in .NET 4 Beta 2.

Comment: Thx for looking into this. I just updated my post with all of my code. I am using the latest code from codeplex.